# WMV scaling in Firefox 3.0.3

Tags: firefox, scaling, firefox-3, wmv

I am having problems with my `WMV` file playing in its original resolution and not scaling to the size of the windows media frame. 
 Here is the code:

```
<p>
  <object height="420" width="585" type="application/x-oleobject"
          standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..."
          codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
          classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" id="mediaPlayer">
    <param value="mms://a1977.v167321.c16732.g.vm.akamaistream.net/7/1977/16732/0/sas-qp.onstreammedia.com/origin/2etrassociates/NSLC/Webinars/Sustaining_Successful_Civic_Engagement_Campus_and_Community_Based_Initiatives-20090409-1804.wmv" name="fileName" />
    <param value="1" name="animationatStart" />
    <param value="1" name="transparentatStart" />
    <param value="1" name="autoStart" />
    <param value="1" name="ShowControls" />
    <param value="0" name="ShowDisplay" />
    <param value="0" name="ShowStatusBar" />
    <param name="AutoSize" value="false" />
    <param value="0" name="loop" />
    <param value="100" name="Volume" />
    <embed height="420" width="585" scale="exactfit" loop="0"
           designtimesp="5311" autostart="1"
           src="mms://a1977.v167321.c16732.g.vm.akamaistream.net/7/1977/16732/0/sas-qp.onstreammedia.com/origin/2etrassociates/NSLC/Webinars/Sustaining_Successful_Civic_Engagement_Campus_and_Community_Based_Initiatives-20090409-1804.wmv"
           videoborder3d="0" showstatusbar="0" showdisplay="0" showtracker="1"
           showcontrols="1" bgcolor="darkblue" autosize="0" displaysize="4"
           name="mediaPlayer" id="mediaPlayer"
           pluginspage="http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/"
           type="application/x-mplayer2" volume="100">
    </embed>
  </object>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="/sites/default/files/download/webinars/Wagner_College-Staten_Island-New_York-Webinar.ppt">
    <strong>Download the Updated PowerPoint presentation for this webinar</strong>
  </a>. (755K ppt)
</p>
```

[And here is the link which](http://servicelearning.org/webinars/Sustaining_Successful_Civic_Engagement-2009.php)
**works fine in IE7 and IE8.**

Comment: object height="420" width="585" type="application/x-oleobject" standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..." codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701" classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" id="mediaPlayer">  <p

Comment: @Larry: I fixed the formatting.

Comment: Obviously, the problem is WMV :). You should use <video> and Theora.